# Does conductance in the transmission line model represent a physical quantity?

Tags: transmission-line

For context, someone asked a question on amateur radio SE which I'm having difficulty completely understanding myself:

[Why is coax loss logarithmic?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/7353/218)

I'm not looking for an answer to that, but rather it's made me realize there are some more fundamental concepts I don't fully understand.

---

Say we take a typical transmission line model, with inductance, capacitance, resistance, and conductance distributed throughout the line:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyIdC2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The characteristic impedance is:

$$ Z_{0}=\sqrt {R+j\omega L \over G+j\omega C} $$

So wouldn't that mean if we expect to have a transmission line with a real characteristic impedance, it must be that \$R/G = L/C\$?

So then I wonder, do non-real characteristic impedance transmission lines exist? Are they typical? What does it even mean to have a non-real characteristic impedance?

If no, my understanding is G represents the conductivity of the dielectric, while R represents the resistivity of the conductor. Each being lossy non-ideal properties I'd guess the goal is to minimize them, but if hope to achieve a real Z<sub>0</sub> this means carefully matching the non-ideal properties of both the conductor and the dielectric, ideally in a way which holds over a wide range of frequencies. Sounds difficult.

Or is it that R and G don't directly correlate to physical quantities, and they are just values mathematically selected to fit the equations to the behavior of the circuit?

Comment: G is shunt leakage conductance.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_condition#Line_characteristics

Comment: It means broad baseband will get distorted in long haul, hence many narrow band carriers are used for data Modems or narrow band for modulated carriers, but loss is \$= \sqrt{RG}) Napiers/m\$

Comment: Is  that nepers?

Comment: Follow-up question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/292728/17608

Answer (score 3):

> non-real characteristic impedance transmission lines exist? Are they typical?

Yes.

An ideal transmission line has R = 0 and G = 0. This gives a real characteristic impedance. But this is an idealization. These numbers are never actually 0 in reality, so the imaginary part of characteristic impedance is never truly 0.

> What does it even mean to have a non-real characteristic impedance?

It means the transmission line is lossy. The sum of output power and reflected power will be (at least slightly) less than the input power.

> but if hope to achieve a real Z0 this means carefully matching the non-ideal properties of both the conductor and the dielectric,

This isn't practical.

More often you just try to get R and G low enough that they can be ignored for practical purposes.

Minimizing G means choosing a dielectric material appropriate for the frequencies you're using.

Minimizing R means using a larger conductor (wider trace on a PCB or larger diameter coax). But this also tends to decrease the maximum frequency before the transmission line goes multi-mode. End result: at high frequencies, you just have to use small geometries and deal with the loss.

Due to *skin effect*, R tends to increase in proportion to \$\sqrt{f}\$, and this will typically dominate the frequency-dependent loss of a transmission line, if the dielectric has been chosen appropriately for the operating frequency band.

> R and G don't directly correlate to physical quantities,

R is pretty directly tied to the conductivity of the conductor material. Skin effect also plays an important role. This is why you see silver-plated conductors on coax meant for high frequencies.

G relates to the polarization behavior of the dielectric, so it's harder to tie down to a specific physical mechanism. Generally if you're choosing dielectrics for high frequency designs, you'll see the loss specified as a *loss tangent*, but it will probably only be specified at a single frequency, which naturally won't be the one you're designing for.

Comment: Can't a transmission line be lossy with a real impedance? Suppose L=C=0 but R and G are nonzero

Comment: @immibis, I don't think there's any physical way to realize that situation, and I've never thought about what it's effect would be. You're probably right, though, that would just be a resistor divider, and it would have some loss.

Comment: You can imagine $\omega L$ and $\omega C$ being very small relative to R and C, though.

Comment: @immibis, you can take the limit of frequency going to 0 and get there. But practically, it's easy to get R in the milliohms per cm (or lower) and G in the nanosiemens per cm, so the losses can be extremely low.

Comment: It can be, but I'm saying the loss *doesn't have to be* extremely low, with a real impedance. Take for instance a 1m length of nichrome wire with DC running through it. Then you have a toaster. Toasters are not lossless transmission lines :P

Comment: If L=C=0 (or close enough) then I think the line isn't a transmission line at all and can be described by lumped models.

Comment: @mbrig That's my intuition too. A non-zero L or C is required to get "time" in the equations somewhere. Can't have a wave without time.

Comment: Also I'd note a resistive T pad satisfies \$Z_0 = \sqrt{R/G}\$, has a real impedance, and is obviously lossy.

Comment: I retract my last statement. If the attenuation constant is the real part of the propagation constant, then I think it would work out that \$Z_0\$ must have a imaginary part to have an attenuation constant less than 1. I guess the reasoning is different for lumped elements like a T pad.

Comment: Well now I've confused myself to the point I need to ask another question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/292728/17608

Answer (score 1):

> do non-real characteristic impedance transmission lines exist? Are
>   they typical? What does it even mean to have a non-real characteristic
>   impedance?

Yes, all transmission lines in the audio range have a complex impedance. Given that R and jwC dominate at "mid audio", the impedance of any regular transmission line becomes \$\sqrt{R/jwC}\$. Note that the suare root of 1/j is equivalent to a phase shift of 45 degrees.

This is why telephone systems model their line impedance with a "complex impedance" rather than using the earlier 600 ohm "fits all" standard: -

[image]

As frequency rises above audio, jwL starts to dominate over R and your get the more familiar \$\sqrt{L/C}\$ version. This happens anywhere from about 100 kHz to over 1 MHz.

Conductance doesn't play any role in a sensibly designed cable until dielectric losses become significant i.e. At high frequencies.