# Must the characteristic impedance of a transmission line be non-real for it to be lossy?

Tags: transmission-line, theory

In [Does conductance in the transmission line model represent a physical quantity?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/292643/17608) it came up that a non-real characteristic impedance just means the line has some loss. With real transmission lines having a little (but perhaps negligible) loss, we could expect all real transmission lines to have a characteristic impedance with at least a small imaginary component.

But is that really true? Let's say \$Z = Y = 1+1j\$. The characteristic impedance of this line is real:

$$ \sqrt{  1+1j \over 1+1j } = 1 $$

And the attenuation constant is 1 [corrected by edit]:

$$ \operatorname{Re}\sqrt{(1+1j)(1+1j)} = 1 $$

Which to my understanding, means this line is lossless. But how can this be when it has both a non-zero conductance and resistance?

Comment: How is your second equation equal to 1?

Comment: Because \$\sqrt{x^2} = x\$, and \$\operatorname{Re}(1+1j) = 1\$.

Comment: Oh yes I was not paying attention to the Re() operator!

Comment: I don't think the question was answered. The answer is no. You describe a lossy distortionless line which has real characteristic impedance

Answer (score 1):

Phil, the real part of the propagation constant is the attenuation constant and this equals: -

\$Re\sqrt{(R+jwL)(G+jwC)}\$ and not the formula you have in your question.

The formula you have used is for characteristic impedance.

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant) wiki page should confirm this (right at the bottom): -

[image]

So, if you do the math at low frequencies (to make life easier) you see that the attenuation constant becomes \$\sqrt{RG}\$ and if R=G=1 then you have a constant of 1 and a lousy highly lossy line. A lossless line has a re(propagation constant) of zero.

Comment: Both the series R and parallel G are resistive and therefore loss components.

Comment: Both the questioner and I know that but, the question is all about the real part of the propagation coefficient.

Comment: Ah whoops, that was a typo. But isn't \$\sqrt{(1+1j)(1+1j)} = 1+1j\$ still?

Comment: At DC the attenuation constant is \$\sqrt{RG}\$ and if R=G=1 then the constant is 1 and therefore this is a big loss. It isn't lossless - it may be that you are confusing distortionless for lossless? A lossless line will have a constant of zero. See this: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjqnPHo9dvSAhWLCsAKHXO4ChkQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ittc.ku.edu%2F~jstiles%2F723%2Fhandouts%2FThe_Lossless_Transmission_Line.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGGX8VR_Sv63vv0c9eRh37u-iYfqQ&sig2=aRArjDbeR3RnbXCDLU7Rag&cad=rja